# How to add object into a list inside of the other list using Java 8 lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a doubts about how to add object into a list inside of the other list using Java 8 lambdas.

let me explain:

I have the follow objects:

Class Object:

```
public class Course{

   private String courseNae;
   private List<Student> studentList;

   /*gets and sets */

}
```

Student Object:

```
public class Student{

   private String studentName;
   private List<Subject> subjectList;

       /*gets and sets */
}
```

Subject Object:

```
public class Subject{

   private String subjectName;
   private String details;
   private double value;

       /*gets and sets */
}
```

I would like to do this but using java 8 lambda:

```
 for(Class course: this.courseList){
        for(Student std: course.getStudentList()){
            if(std.getStudentName().equals(name)) {
                std.getSubjectList()
                        .add(Subject.newBuilder()
                        .subjectName(infoName)
                        .details("fofofofof")
                        .value(10.0)
                        .build());
            }
        }
    }
```

In general: 
 - I would like find the studant name into my Course list

- Once that I found the student name I would like to add a new subject info 
  inside of the Subject list.

Comment: and you have tried...?

Comment: The word is stud***e***nt, not studant. And `class` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: Defining a `Class` class isn't a good idea either, I suggest using `Course` instead.

Comment: I change my post, thanks for your feedback

Comment: Hi, please show some effort using the stream API. Requesting a *translation* from imperative to functional & streams doesn't seem to be the best approach to be given a correct answer. Do some research, try something, and if you get stuck, ask a question here.

Comment: Possible bug: if the student is in multiple courses, your example code will add the subject to them multiple times. It seems strange to have to search through courses in order to find a student by their name, anyway. Consider keeping a separate `Map<String, Student>` (string being the name) that includes all students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a possible solution for your problem:

**Code:**

```
courseList.stream()
          .map(Course::getStudentList)
          .flatMap(Collection::stream)
          .filter(student -> student.getStudentName().equals(name))
          .findFirst()
          .map(Student::getSubjectList)
          .ifPresent(subjectList -> subjectList.add(
              Subject.newBuilder()
                     .subjectName(infoName)
                     .details("fofofofof")
                     .value(10.0)
                     .build())
          );
```

**Explanation:**

- `.map(Course::getStudentList)` will transform the input `List<Course>` to a stream of `List<Student>`
- `.flatMap(Collection::stream)` will flatten the given `List<Student>` to a stream of `Student`
- `.filter(...)` will filter the stream so that only students with matching names are streamed
- `.findFirst()` will find the first item of the given stream
- `.map(Student::getSubjectList)` will now transform the stream of students to a stream of `List<Subject>`
- `.ifPresent(...)` will be executed if we found an according, matching student

**Notes:**

- The method call that look like that: `Course::getStudentList` are so called method references. Read more about them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).
- Read more about streams [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)
- Read more about `Optional` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)